# JavaScript `undefined` vs `void 0`

Tags: javascript, undefined, void

What exactly is the difference between `undefined` and  `void 0` ?

Which is preferred and why?

Comment: Most recent answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/19369078/1903116 , in a duplicate question.

Comment: Related posts - [difference between “void 0 ” and “undefined”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4806286/465053), [Why does void in Javascript require an argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19367589/465053), [What is the point of void operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/666936/465053), & [What does “javascript:void(0)” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1291942/465053)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The difference is that some browsers allow you to overwrite the value of `undefined`. However, `void anything` always returns real *undefined*.

```js
(function (undefined) {

undefined = 1;
console.log(!!undefined); //true
console.log(!!void 0); //false

})();
```

Comment: `void` is an operator and not a function so you dont have to use `void()`.

Comment: If browsers let you redefine `undefined`, shouldn't such browsers therefore also *use* the redefined `undefined` in these cases? What possible point could there be in redefining `undefined` otherwise?

Comment: @devios1 It does. Anywhere `window.undefined` is referenced, it will have the new value which is what the code above shows.

Comment: @ManPersonson In that case it's not redefining it, it's just defining a similarly-named value in a different scope (window).

Comment: `undefined` is a primitive value. There is no meaningful distinction there. It has exactly the same consequence for your program.

Comment: does it make to define `undefined`? Here we are using primitive `undefined` rather a variable

Comment: which browser overwrite the value of undefined?

Comment: the answer not right anymore!
![](https://img2020.cnblogs.com/blog/740516/202009/740516-20200927130728713-127423232.png)

Comment: Which browser allows overwrite undefined? tried Chrome, Safari and Firefox, none of them allows as of now.

Comment: @Haijin You could overwrite undefined in IE8 and older, or any engine that runs ES3

Comment: @Haijin Any modern browser can overwrite `undefined` in any scope other than the global scope. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined#description

Answer (score 31):

`undefined` [has normal variable semantics that not even strict mode can fix](http://jsfiddle.net/9y2sr/) and requires run-time look-up. It can be shadowed
like any other variable, and the default global variable `undefined` is not read-only in ES3.

`void 0` is effectively a compile time bulletproof constant for `undefined` with no look-up requirements. It is 
like writing `null` or `true`, instead of looking up a variable value. It works out of the box without any safety arguments and is shorter to write. It is better in every way.

Comment: Shorter just in uncompressed code; if you use an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), you can minify `undefined` to something like `a`, while `void 0` is not minifiable :)

Comment: @gustavohenke But what about gzip? If you minify you might get all different letters like `a` `b` `c` in different closures for `undefined`. Where as `void 0` is `void 0` anywhere. Anyways, this technique will surely confuse the JITs which already optimize `undefined` (FF, Chrome but not IE10) because it's a global constant and even static analysis can see if it's shadowed. With this, you turn it into a normal variable look-up and it's not a compile-time constant for sure. Of course that might not matter but that wasn't the argument :P

Comment: @gustavohenke see http://pastebin.com/DDTp7E9c `void 0` and `undefined` are recognized as compile-time constants but saving it into a variable is totally different

Answer (score 0):

Use `undefined`. Its more commonly known than `void(0)`.

Comment: Just because it's more commonly known doesn't mean it's better or can be used interchangeably.

Comment: Agree with @daniel-a-white - I just want to return `undefined` explicitly, not result of operator (of course it is technically the same, but it's **more human readable**)

Answer (score -3):

Parentheses here are optional, `void 0`, `void(0)` and `void (0)` are equivalent. The `void` is a unary operator with a right-to-left associativity, hence the value is placed at the right of it:

`void <VALUE>`.

For second question, you need to use `undefined` directly while avoiding unneeded operand evaluation to retrieve the same `undefined` value.

More info in the reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void

Comment: I dont think parentheses are optional because "JS is very loose at syntax", but because `void` is an operator not a function.

Comment: 'you need to use `undefined` directly while avoiding unneeded operand evaluation to retrieve the same `undefined` value.' – what does that even mean?

Comment: **This is actually not true!** `undefined` is a global (on to of `window`) variable which holds by default the value of the result operator `void 0` and in some old browsers can be "re-writable".

Comment: Saying that the parens are optional is not very accurate.  The operator does not take parens, period.  They are not optional at all, they are not there.  However the value is an expression, and of course expressions can have parens.  You could write `void (1-1)`.  Saying that the parens are optional is like saying that unary function calls support multiple parens: `console.log((((23))))`.