# Should I use `void 0` or `undefined` in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Should I use `void 0` or `undefined` in JavaScript to unassign a value, for example:

```
event.returnValue = void 0;
```

or

```
event.returnValue = undefined;
```

Comment: There is no difference. `void 0` always returned undefined.

Comment: `event.returnValue` should be either `true` or false`, what is the case ?

Comment: look out chicken little!!! undefined is being defined all the time, judging from the answers below. really?

Comment: @RecoveringSince2003, `returnValue` may contain a string for `onbeforeunload`, for example.

Comment: You should use `void "do I understand why I'm doing this?"`

Comment: @user2736012, do you?

Comment: I understand enough to not redefined the value of `undefined`. That's all one needs.

Comment: `event.returnValue` is alternative of `event.preventDefault()` which is for `IE-8` and lower to cancel the default behavior using `false`, but i didn't get what did you mean.

Comment: @user2736012, did I say I'm redefining `undefined`? My JavaScript module is self-contained and should be able to run in any context.

Comment: @avo: Then why would you use `void 0`?

Comment: If your module is self-contained then you can take steps to ensure that inside the module `undefined` actually has the value `undefined` even when running in older browsers that allow the `undefined` global to be set to other values. @user2736012 - The point is that (in older browsers) some other included library may potentially have changed the value of `undefined` as a global, so it isn't completely safe to assume that `undefined` will always actually have the value `undefined`.

Comment: @nnnnnn: IMO, if a developer loads a library that does this, that's the same as the developer doing it. Either way, a scoped `undefined` is a better solution.

Comment: To the down-voter: thank you for explaining why.

Comment: @user2736012, I disagree that I should be trying to make sure `undefined` is correct in my scope (and fix it otherwise), if I don't use it at all. I'd stick with `void 0`.

Comment: @user2736012, if you found it's a duplicate, feel free to use Close link. But thanks for explaining the reason to down-vote, usually people just don't.

Comment: @user2736012 - The point is that you might be writing a library that is used by other people who don't take care about these things, so you need to ensure your own code copes. If you don't supply code to other people then you don't have to worry.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Yes, I agree. That's why I said a scoped `undefined` is a good solution. I think anyone writing a public library will have enough sense to encapsulate their variables, and make a safe `undefined`. Though I wouldn't suggest trying to solve all "environment corruption" problems. At some point the end users just need to be responsible for their own bad code.

Comment: There is a difference -- `void 0` takes less bytes. If the goal is to minify the code, then `void 0` is better than `undefined`. But, this should be the job of whatever minifier you use to minify your code.

Comment: What about ```[][0]```? Is it safe Enough?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

If you are using a modern browser, (which supports JavaScript 1.8.5) using `undefined` and `void 0` would most likely yield the same result ([since `undefined` is made not writable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined#Description)), except that the `void` can accept an expression as parameter and evaluate it.

**In older browsers**, (which do not support JavaScript 1.8.5) it is better to use `void 0`. Look at this example:

```
console.log(undefined);
var undefined = 1;
console.log(undefined);
```

It will print

```
1
```

`undefined` is actually a global property - it's not a keyword. So, undefined can be changed, where as `void` is an operator, which cannot be overridden in JavaScript and always returns the value `undefined`. Just check this answer which I gave earlier today for a similar question, [Why does void in Javascript require an argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19367635/1903116).

**Conclusion:**

So, if you are concerned about compatibility, it is better to go with `void 0`.

Comment: While it is a variable, it was given `[[Writable]]: false` [in ES5](http://es5.github.io/#x15.1.1.3). So, the example only *works* in ES3-based engines, like IE 8 and older.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski depends on [the scope...](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/gFtJW/)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Included reference to the fact that `undefined` is made not writable. Thanks for pointing it out. Please check.

Comment: Note that plenty of people _are_ still using IE8 (for example it's forced upon me by my employer), so better safe than sorry.

Comment: I don't see the compatibility argument. While it may be overwritable in older environments, no one *does* overwrite it. I think `undefined` is better because a) it's more clear and b) you can easily make it a minifyable variable.

Comment: @thefourtheye, You might want to migrate/post this answer to [the original thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5716976/632951) that has more views.

Comment: `undefined` is still writable in modern browsers in any scope other than the global scope. No one _should_ write to it, but if you're writing some sort of compiler/minifier, it sounds like it would be safer to use `void 0`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined#description

Answer (score 15):

"void 0" is safer. "undefined" is a value, like any other. It's possible to overwrite that value with another:

```
undefined = 3;
```

That would change the meaning of your event.returnValue had you used undefined. "void" is a keyword, though, and its meaning can't be changed. "void 0" will always give the value undefined.

Comment: Not in any modern browser it's not.

Comment: @ColinDeClue depends on [the scope...](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/gFtJW/)

Comment: @canon: So then if you write properly scoped code, it's impossible for someone to overwrite `undefined` for you?

Comment: @ColinDeClue - At work I use IE8, because I don't have control over the desktop environment. My point being that we have to code pages on the assumption that they might run in older browsers. (Not that it isn't easy to deal with `undefined`.)

Comment: @nnnnnn: It depends on your requirements, really. Sometimes, yes, you need to code with the assumption it needs to work on IE8. Other times that would increase the cost dramatically, and potentially decreased the feature set.

Comment: "Safer"? Whoever overwrites it on his own page is silly, and it's his own fault. If someone else can overwrite it on your page, you've got a more serious problem.

Comment: @Bergi, some of us write libraries that are used on other people's pages, not just our own. Writing a library that can work on anyone's page (regardless of browser version or "silly" faults) requires techniques like this one.

Comment: @Zach: Every library does fail on a page whose ES environment is compromised enough. Still, to "fix" this particular fail you should not use `void`, but an IEFE: `(function(undefined){ /* use 'undefined' here */ })(void 0);`

Comment: @Bergi I noticed you are still using `void 0` in your example of how to fix it. :) Of course you don't have to -- once you're using a function, you could do `(function(undefined) { /* use 'undefined' here */ })();` (not passing a parameter gives the value undefined), or this: `(function() { var undefined = (function(){})(); /* use 'undefined' here */ })();` The point being, there are lots of ways to get the value undefined. `void 0` is strictly safer than just using `undefined` without a function scope.

Answer (score 1):

> The void operator is often used merely to obtain the undefined primitive value, usually using “void(0)” (which is equivalent to “void 0”). In these cases, the global variable undefined can be used instead (assuming it has not been assigned to a non-default value).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1291950/2876804

Just use undefined, since they will both evaluate to it.

Comment: -1: I would agree to just use undefined for normal code, but it's not always true that they'll both evaluate to it. This answer also doesn't discuss why one would use one alternative over the other, which does have practical reasoning.

Comment: @Khan This and another user basically copied/pasted from other questions.