# JavaScript void 0 vs undefined

Tags: javascript

what is the difference between **`void 0`** and **`undefined`** in the following contexts?

```
function Test(value) {
    if(value === void 0) {
        value = 123;
    }
    this.value = value;
}
```

```
function Test(value) {
    if(value === undefined) {
        value = 123;
    }
    this.value = value;
}
```

```
function Test(value) {
    this.value = value || 123;
}
```

AFAIK, all three produce the same result.

```
undefined === void 0
// true
```

Thus, what is the difference between `undefined` and `void 0`, and what benefit does one have over the other?

Comment: There are multiple duplicates... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369023/should-i-be-using-void-0-or-undefined-in-javascript 
Older versions used void 0

Comment: The last version produces different results. Try with `Test(0)`. Either way, `void` is an operator that returns `undefined`.

Comment: Please remember that `undefined` is now immutable in the global scope, other closures may shadow this.