# Why compare to void 0 instead of undefined? (TypeScript nullish coalescing operator)

Tags: javascript, typescript

If you aren't familiar with the new TypeScript "nullish coalescing operator" (`??`), it's documented here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#nullish-coalescing

> You can think of this feature - the ?? operator - as a way to “fall back” to a default value when dealing with `null` or `undefined`.

I've just used this for the first time in some code, and I noticed something odd about the way the operator is translated into JavaScript. Using the [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/), you can see that this code:

```
const message: string = process.env.FOO ?? 'bar';
```

Is translated into this:

```
"use strict";
var _a;
const message = (_a = process.env.FOO, (_a !== null && _a !== void 0 ? _a : 'bar'));
```

Since `??` tests for null or undefined values, why compare to `void 0` instead of `undefined`? I can't think of anything other than perhaps `void 0` is just a few characters shorter than `undefined`. Is there a better reason than that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I use \`void 0\` or \`undefined\` in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369023/should-i-use-void-0-or-undefined-in-javascript)

Comment: @mdexp, that seems to make sense. I haven't had to worry about JavaScript so ancient that `undefined` could change value, but I guess TypeScript is by default trying to translate to the oldest version of JavaScript possible when it can.

Comment: typescript is a Microsoft invention, so, of course it translates to code that can be run on ancient browsers :p that's all MicroSoft have ... ancient browsers :p

Comment: @Jaromanda X, 