# Logical expression

Tags: javascript

Is there any difference between the below statements:

1. `if(newValue && newValue != '')` and
2. `if(newValue != '')`

I have observed expression 1 in many scripts but always got confused.

Please assist!

Comment: The first will reject all other falsy values not weakly equal to the empty string.

Answer (score 3):

> if(newValue && newValue != '').

This guards against a value of `null` or `undefined`.

Out of the possible `''`, `0`, `false`, `undefined` and `null`, only the last two are not equal to `''` (using `!=`), requiring the extra condition.

```
console.log(null && null != '') // null -> falsy
console.log(null != '') // truthy

var undef = void 0;

console.log(undef && undef != '') // undefined -> falsy
console.log(undef != '') // truthy
```

Comment: @JanDvorak What else then?

Comment: Wow... I thought `0!=''` was true

Comment: @JanDvorak To be honest, I evaluated them all to be sure ;-)

Comment: What about `undefined`? `undefined !== null`.

Comment: What is `var undef = void 0;`? I have never seen this syntax before but apparently it works.

Comment: @JanDvorak It's an expression to get `undefined` literal, always :)

Comment: Isn't `(function(u){return u})()` or `[][0]` (or `[][[]]` if you hate alphanumerics) a better way to get `undefined`?

Comment: Cf.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806286/difference-between-void-0-and-undefined

Comment: @JanDvorak My logic is that `void 0` is shorter than the first and clearer than the second (and even clearer than the third) :) I would use your first option if I already had a closure though.

Comment: jQuery uses the first approach to get `undefined`; the whole library is wrapped in a single huge IIFE to capture `window`, `document` and compute `undefined`.

Comment: @JanDvorak Yup, it's a good option; to illustrate an example though, I feel it would distract too much ... not saying `void 0` doesn't distract, but hey, we're all here to learn ya? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Answer is no,

1) for `(newValue && newValue != '')`,it checks whether newValue exist(non false values) and its not empty

2) for `if(newValue != '')`,it only checks whether newValue is not empty

Comment: Thank you so much Milind, I got it now!

Comment: Is there any truthy value weakly equal to the empty string?

Comment: You mean the answer is "yes" because there is a difference between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Just one more thin I thought worth adding to the answers already posted.
As you, the OP, say: you've seen the first expression in existing code many times, so you've probably seen things like this:

```
if (foo && foo.bar)
{
    foo.bar();
}
```

In this case, this is to avoid errors in certain browsers. In most modern browsers accessing somehting like `localStorage.doesNotExist` won't raise errors, but not all browsers support this so we: first check if the `localStorage` object exists, and if so, if the property can be resolved to a non-falsy value.

The same logic applies to methods of objects, that may be different in various browsers:

```
var domElement = document.getElementById('foobar');//might not exist, though
if (domElement && domElement.addEventListener)
{//does element exist && does it have a method called addEventListener
    domElement.addEventListener('click', functionRef, false);
}
else if (domElement && domElement.attachEvent)
{
    domElement.attachEvent('onclick', functionRef);
}
```

if you were to omit the first `domElement` in the if statement, and simply write `domElement.addEventListener`, that *could* be the same as writing `null.addEventListener` which throws a *TypeError* (because you're trying to access a property on a primitive value)