# Why should I use underscore's isUndefined(x) over x === undefined?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

Is there any benefit in using isUndefined?  Is it worth an extra function call?  It's not any more readable.

Comment: @JoeSwindell Read the title

Comment: @JoeSwindell As compared to `x === undefined`.

Comment: Well, it does `_.isUndefined = function(obj) {
 return obj === void 0; };`, so it's obviously not exactly the same.

Comment: ^ and based on that, this is a duplicate -> **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806286/difference-between-void-0-and-undefined**

Comment: .isUndefined returns true in underscore.js if it is undefined. It's not the same.

Comment: @adeneo That question is specifically about `void 0` vs `undefined` with no mention about `_.isUndefined()`, so I would say this is not a duplicate.

Comment: @cpburnz - and read my comment, `void 0` is exactly what underscore does, and it's the only thing it does, so why would it not be dupe.

Comment: @adeneo If this question was to be closed as a duplicate, a person would be directed to that other question talking about the difference between `void 0` and `undefined` which to them would not necessarily answer how `_.isUndefined()` differs from `undefined` unless they knew how `_.isUndefined()` was defined in which case they would not be looking up this question but the other.

Comment: The real answer is that using `void` ensures the object is compared against `undefined`, as `void 0` returns `undefined`, and `void` is a reserved keyword so it can't be overwritten in any scope, shape or form, writing `var void` is in fact a syntax error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The name `undefined` can be shadowed. That is, somebody could do this

```
var undefined = 5;
```

and break the code that uses `x === undefined` (see note at bottom). To get around this safely, you can use

```
typeof x === 'undefined'
```

or

```
x === void 0
```

which is exactly what the underscore function does.

---

Note: Since ECMAScript 5, `undefined` is read-only. In older browser, the global `undefined` can be redefined. Even in newer browsers, `undefined` can be shadowed by a local variable:

```
function f() {
  var undefined = 5;
  return undefined;
}
f() // returns 5
```

Comment: In EcmaScript 5 `undefined` is read-only, so it's not an issue, but you could declare a local variable with that name, but then it would generally be your own mistake.