# Javascript difference between typeof undefined and void?

Tags: javascript

While doing some typescript I came over this thing I havent seen before in javascript.

```
constructor(public x: number = 0, public y: string = "none"){
        this.color = "red";
    }
```

that part is compiling into:

```
    if (x === void 0) { x = 0; }
    if (y === void 0) { y = "none"; }
```

But shouldn't it be `typeof x === 'undefined'`? if not, which one is better and why?

thanks

Comment: `void 0` gives the value `undefined` but is less typing. (Except of course in your case you didn't manually type it.) So `x === void 0` is like saying `x === undefined` but slightly shorter. `typeof x === 'undefined'` is a long way of testing the same thing, and necessary only if you're not sure if the `x` variable has even been declared - but in this case you know it definitely *is* declared since it's a function argument.

Comment: @nnnnnn Seems like that might be worthy of promoting to an answer if you add a little more detail / a reference to explain to the OP why `void 0 === undefined`

Comment: In a modern JavaScript interpreter there's no meaningful difference.

Comment: @Pointy yes, I know that (assuming no stupid redefiniton) but clearly the OP doesn't yet... I was too lazy to dig up a link and besides, nnnnnn bear me to it. Suppose I should dig one out now: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4806358/156755

Comment: @nnnnnn I did saw the link now it does make more sense, but I was just confuse about it, since in my local compiler typescript goes with typeof `x === 'undefined'` but in the live  playground goes  `(x === void 0)` which made curiouse to see if there was a really and meaningful difference

Comment: @Basic I didnt see that link before, well this does prove why they decide it change the output of the code, since `void` perform faster with less code, cheers

Comment: For the curious. One big motiviation for this change is `void 0` takes lesser characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are differences.

If you're checking for a global variable `x`,
then `typeof x === 'undefined'` will return `true` and `x === void 0` throw a `ReferenceError`.
You would need to use `window.x === void 0` to get `true`.  However in this case it knows that `x` will at least be set to `undefined` because it is a function parameter, so that error will never be an issue.

I think for readability sake, I would prefer to use `typeof x === 'undefined'`.

Comment: You think `typeof x === 'undefined'` is *more* readable? For sound programming practices sake, I'd never do that. Getting a `ReferenceError` is valuable information.

Comment: @Wio Now I do believe the MS took the right approach when they changed to `void` to test for variables... look here http://typeofnan.blogspot.com/2011/01/typeof-is-fast.html looks like this way is a lot faster, so I guess this way is better, dont you think?

Comment: When I change `undef` to `void 0`, I'm seeing `typeof` win. I said `typeof x === 'undefined'` is more readable, because more are familiar with `undefined` than they are with `void`.